# In American English, how to make the /ɪər/ sound?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation

For example: here, dear, clear.
I sometimes hear American people when saying those words, the words come out from deep into their throats. But, still, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Clear UK /klɪər/,  US / klɪr/

Comment: Dear UK /dɪər/, US /dɪr/

Comment: Here UK / hɪər/ US / hɪr/

Comment: In ɪəʳ, the r is not pronounced in BrE, unless the sound comes before a vowel (as in dearest, dear Ann). In AmE, the r is always pronounced, and the sound is often written as ɪr .

Comment: I think once you get the American /r/ sound right, you'll have no problem with those words.

Comment: @Mia so the /ɪ/ in /hɪr/ (here) should be pronounced like the /ɪ/ in sit or the /i:/ in bee? I hear them more like /hi:r/ than /hɪr/ ?

Comment: @Little Straw purple: No, they are not the same.  /i:/ sound is longer than  /I/ . I think it's best to just listen to the difference if you want to understand how to pronounce words that contain these sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice to pronounce the words "here", " dear" and " clear"in American English, you need to make /iy/ sound. In order to make this sound ,set your lips 3/8 inch (1cm) apart.Widen your lips into a big smile. The sound is long. Count to two silently to be sure it is long enough.

Examples:

here

hear

ear

tier

Now I would also like to discuss /eə/ sound because I wanted  you to compare them and see how they differ.

To make this sound, keep your jaw halfway open. The lips are 1/2 inch (1.3cm) apart. Tense your lips, and form a wide, downward smile. Begin the sound, then move your lips close together into the /ə/ position.

You can practice saying the following words, which feature this vowel sound:

bear

chair

Where

hair

Spare

pair

Cram

They're

Theirs

Now Compare ear /iy/, /ɪ/  with

```
        air /eər/
```

Note: In /ɪəʳ/ as in "Near", the r is not pronounced in BrE, unless the sound comes before a vowel (as in dearest, dear Ann). In AmE, the r is always pronounced, and the sound is often written as /ɪr/.

Comment: "Cram"? How does that sound similar to the others?

Comment: You should make it clearer that "bear" and "ear" have different sounds. I'm not sure why you're discussing the former at all, since the question only asked about the latter.

Comment: Cram /kræm/,/kreəm/         laugh/læf/,/leəf/

Comment: @Deusovi Wikipedia has [a description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8a%E2%9F%A9#.C3.A6_tensing) of that phenomenon. Which of those words sound like each other can depend a lot on one's accent.